# Mapping of lists according to labels into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have different observations according to different labels.
In the following example, we have different measures: `a`, `b` or
`c`. And for each variable, we can get some values.

Observation 1: we have some values for all `a`, `b` and
`c`

```
['a','b','c']
['value_a_1','value_b_1','value_c_1']
```

Observation 2: we only have `a` and `c`.

```
['a','c']
['value_a_2','value_c_2']
```

And we can see that the mesure b is absent.

**Question 1**

How to transform the observation 2 into:

```
['value_a_2',None,'value_c_2']
```

**Question 2**

And I also would like to create a DataFrame (pandas) like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['value_a_1','value_b_1','value_c_1'],['value_a_2',None,'value_c_2']],columns=['a','b','c'])
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `value_c_2` for the value at `c, 1` in your image?

Comment: Where will you read observations from? Are they all in separate files? Are they stored as csv? Have you tried some code and got a specific error?